# sys/stat.h returning wrong size

Tags: c, stat, unistd.h

I am using

1. unistd.h
2. sys/stat.h

and what is interesting is that `st_size` is bigger than the value returned after `read()`?
`st.st_size` returns `644` - `read()` returns `606`,
Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the file descriptor set for non-blocking?  Is the file a plain disk file, or is there anything special about it.  Show some code too.

Comment: `read()` is allowed to read and return fewer bytes than were requested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Size of file and size of stream may not match. For example, when you open file in text mode, OS can translate multi-byte EOL sequences into single char. This is usually visible on Windows, but if you have a Windows file on Linux, the effect can be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The memory is allocated in multiples of blocks (st_blocks). The remaining bytes you noticed are due to block alignment.

If you check the value of `st.st_blocks` you will see that it is a good divisor for `644`, while not to 606.

So, if you want to know the real size occupied with data, do not use `st_size`.